# How to Edit/add/remove options from streamlit st.selectbox during runtime

Tags: streamlit

I want to allow the user to type in new options for streamlit `st.selectbox` during runtime or edit/delete existing options. I presume a combination of `st.text_input` and `st.selectbox`, plus an add, remove buttons will do the job. But seems over complicated.

Comment: I think this discussion can help [Dynamic selectbox opitions based on the input of text_input](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/dynamic-selectbox-opitions-based-on-the-input-of-text-input/7590)